# IF/CASE statement OR MySQL OR array for get category name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, optimization, if-statement

On my site I got entries which have category. Site have only 5 categories, so I have dilemma:

---

Make relationship between **category** table and **entries** (category_id) table

**OR**

Make method which return category name via IF/CASE statement? Like:

```
case @entry.category.id
  when 1
    "Games"
  when 2
    "Movies"
  when 3
    "Fun"
  [...]
end
```

(I remind that I must get 10 category name per page)

**OR**

Use array:

```
cat[1] = "Games"
cat[2] = "Movies"
cat[3] = "Fun"

[...]

<%= cat[@entry.category.id] %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this relation definitely belongs into the database. (adding a category table)

it is the most sane and most scalable option.

It is also the cleanest, because you break the seperation of data, display and logic (MVC: model, view, controller) when hardcoding the categories in your application.

you can easily select the item AND its category with a single query:

```
SELECT item.*, category.name 
FROM item
LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = item.category_id
WHERE some=condition
```

there are similar queries for INSERTs and UPDATEs (at least in MySQL), so you never need a second query.

Comment: Because I must sent addtional query.
_Phyo Wai Win_ is better I think. I don't must sent query.

Comment: I heared about JOINs, but I don't know it so much. I must learn how to use it.
But Phyo Wai Win way is still more optimal, I think.

@EDIT I talking about Phyo Wai Win's 2nd way (where he use array).
Thanks for help btw. :)

Comment: i don't see at all how that is more optimal to spread your data across several sources (here: DB and hard coded application source) .. but you choose anyway. ;-)

Comment: Because it's in database and MySQL for eg. always get addtional data by JOIN, right?

But maybe You are right. Thanks for help. I will go Your way :)

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you care about category is "name", then you should just store the category_name in the entries table.

OR

Make a constant CATEGORY_NAME and wrapper method to get the name with id in the entries table (without using Category table/model at all). eg.,

```
class Entry
  CATEGORY_NAME = [ "Games", "Movies", "Fun"]

  def category_name 
    CATEGORY_NAME[cat_id]  #cat_id being just 0,1,2 .. depends how you want to store
  end
  ...
```

I am sure there are many ways to achieve this anyway.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I will not store category name in category_name because it's take storage.
But You 2nd method is really good.

Comment: it does not only take storage, it also conflicts with the rules of database normalization. it degrades performance, wastes storage and adds complexity. when "Games" should be changed to "Play", its better to change a single category entry in the database than touch all the item entries.

Comment: Although I agree with the fact about database normalization, I am not sure performance at all (2nd example). It saves only array index id (cat_id) which picks up from array. I do not believe it's any harder to change "Games" to "Play" than using another table Category to as a reference (with 5 categories only!). And why would you need to touch all the item entries to change the array CATEGORY_NAME?

Comment: If I will use database, I must use index etc. So, It's not easy at all.